# "This webpage is not available ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH" - error for my website after installing SSL

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, hsts

I have enabled comodo SSL and HSTS for my website. But shortly after that, many users are complaining they get this error in chrome:

> This webpage is not available ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Firefox doesn't have that issue.

How can I help them to overcome this problem? Even if I disable HTTPS, site still redirect to HTTPS.

Comment: Could it be that you still use ssl3? Run https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to get some very thorough diagnostics - please add the findings of that test to your question as it will help zoom in on the issue.

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest did not say anything about error. Got A grade from them. But still many of our customers face that error.

Comment: Is your certificate or any intermediate 1024 bits? Chrome doesn't like that. OTOH, this question is sort of offtopic, you may want to move it to serverfault.

Comment: I have all certificates with 2048 bits. Hmm, Leave it then, seems some old certificate is cached in those browsers.

Comment: That's exactly what I encountered as well, throw these old certificates out of the browser cache and you should be OK.

Comment: I have this issue too. win8, my account doesn't have any issue. however, in my son's account, when navigate to google.com from both chrome and firefox, it shows this error. IE 11 worked ok. uninstall/reinstall chrome doesn't work. anyone can help?

Comment: i see this for perfectly A grade reports: https://img.shields.io/circleci/project/BrightFlair/PHP.Gt.svg / https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=img.shields.io ??? "Detail" message is: "A secure connection cannot be established because this site uses an unsupported protocol." It's not written *which* protocol is unsupported. And ths probably should me moved to super-user or serverfault.